# Loading many js files with head.js. Adblock blocks adsense script, that sends the page on an infinite loading loop

Tags: javascript, loops, loader, infinite, head.js

I'm trying to load a bunch of javascripts with head.js. I'm also loading [Google Adsense javascript file](http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js) with headjs.

When I have AdBlock on and try to refresh the page (from browser cache) it keeps loading forever. I can see in the inspector that the adblock script has failed to load, and all my other scripts are **pending**.

Funny thing is some of the scripts have loaded already, and those have already been rendered, even though it says pending. The rest of the scripts have not finished loading yet but head.ready fired already, which isn't supposed to happen until all the scripts have finished loading. The code dependent on those files are throwing up errors.

**On hard reloads the page load fine. From browser cache the page loads fine, the second time around.** It's the **first load from browser cache** that's causing me trouble.

Here's my inspector, I'd greatly appreciate any and all help :)

[image: You can see my inspector here:]

Comment: Some script loaders don't work very well if the chain is broken. It may be what is happening. I'd experiment with other loaders like Labjs or such to see if they can handle a broken chain

Comment: Right now I'm loading the adsense script at the bottom of the page and not via head.js. I will try labjs.

Thanks :)

Comment: I read somewhere that head.js and some of the others will break or have race conditions if any inline scripts are used in the page - I am not super familiar with them but that might be something to watch our for.